# zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, package, installation, python-wheel

I am installing Prodigy,

( a software for data annotation).  I am using windows 10, Python 3.7. pip is updated  I need to use wheel python:

https://github.com/MacPython/wiki/wiki/Spinning-wheels

when I write in my anaconda
:
'''
pip install prodigy-1.7.1-cp35.cp36.cp37-cp35m.cp36m.cp37m-win_amd64.whl
'''
(based on instruction in website)

https://prodi.gy/docs/

**I faced with this error (zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file)**

'''
ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py”, line 178, in main status = self.run(options, args) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py”, line 352, in run resolver.resolve(requirement_set) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py”, line 131, in resolve self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py”, line 294, in _resolve_one abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py”, line 242, in _get_abstract_dist_for self.require_hashes File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py”, line 353, in prepare_linked_requirement progress_bar=self.progress_bar File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py”, line 873, in unpack_url unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py”, line 807, in unpack_file_url unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\misc.py”, line 628, in unpack_file flatten=not filename.endswith(’.whl’) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\misc.py”, line 505, in unzip_file zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True) File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py”, line 1222, in init self._RealGetContents() File “c:\users\moha\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py”, line 1289, in _RealGetContents raise BadZipFile(“File is not a zip file”) zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
'''

can anyone let me know what should I do?

Comment: you may have just gotten unlucky, did you try redownloading the whl?

Comment: My first thought is also this, regarding the comment of the support center, the volume of the file should be more than my recent file, I asked again my professor to re-check his email , thank you any way

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that there was a problem reading the package source file when installing. Although they are referred as wheels they are actually zip files.

There are many reasons why you might see this exception. The most common reason is that there was a problem with downloading/storing.

The most common solution is to try install again. This might need removing old download in some cache. Read logs to see where the cache is. You can also look for the the file by its name.