# File is not a zip file || Instapy Problem

Tags: python, automation, instapy

I'm using instapy, but when I run a code this message appears on my cmd

Does anyone know what this problem might be?

```
    ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.
Workspace in use: "C:/Users/lggal/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lggal\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\hastag.py", line 4, in <module>
    session = InstaPy(username='thedesignerofdark', password='Thewitcher2020')
  File "C:\Users\lggal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "C:\Users\lggal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 122, in set_selenium_local_session
    driver_path = geckodriver_path or get_geckodriver()
  File "C:\Users\lggal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 38, in get_geckodriver
    sym_path = gdd.download_and_install()[1]
  File "C:\Users\lggal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\webdriverdownloader\webdriverdownloader.py", line 195, in download_and_install
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(self.get_download_path(version), filename), mode="r") as driver_zipfile:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: hi, perhaps some dependencies need to be upgraded? https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/4939 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921092/zipfile-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file